# Calling R functions from Julia

Tags: julia

Is there a convenient way to call R functions from Julia?

If so, what mechanisms for doing so exist? (Potentially ranging from simply calling an R script from the shell & hand-coding the I/O to/from Julia, to interacting with an R environment over multiple Julia calls with Julia DataFrames being seamlessly converted to/from R DataFrames).

Comment: https://github.com/lgautier/Rif.jl is the closest thing, but may be somewhat out of date vs. Julia trunk.

Comment: Rif.jl is now working with Julia 0.3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Calling R scripts and handcoding I/O is the best way to work with R for the moment. We have functions for reading the RDA binary format that R likes and should add some tools for working with it more easily and also writing data in that format, which will speed up I/O considerably relative to passing CSV files around -- which I've done in the past.

Converting between R and Julia DataFrames could be done, but would be quite costly as Julia isn't using a binary representation of data (e.g. `NA`) that's nearly equivalent to R's. So you'd need to do some non-trivial work to make this work in a way that would be substantially more efficient than using the RDA binary format.

One thing that would be really nice is to build solid Thrift bindings for both R and Julia and then call back and forth using those bindings.

Comment: If Julia had Protocol Buffers suggest you could use RProtoBuf on the other side.  And just curious: how to you deserialize the RData file (RDA does not exist as an acronym) without requiring an R engine?  Is there something generic other languages can borrow?

Comment: Hello John, has there been any progress on this?

Answer (score 3):

For calling out to R from within Julia, the [RCall](https://github.com/JuliaStats/RCall.jl) package is currently your best bet. For calling out to Julia from within R, try the [RJulia](https://github.com/armgong/RJulia) package. Both are a bit in the works.